# 100% CPU Usage ASP.NET App

Tags: asp.net, performance

I am using an ASP.NET application. On click of any control in the page, it is found that the CPU usage goes to 100% which result in slow response. And to come to the OnInit/Page_load it took around 9-10 seconds of time. During check in the task manager, there is one mscorsvw.exe running in the background and it tooks most of the CPU usage.

Can somebody provide any input/hint, what could be the issue.

Comment: This question is too vague. Could you provide more details about the application? Maybe some code?

Comment: -1 A quick Google search reveals: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2005/04/27/412838.aspx Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for asking questions. "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?"

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the Mscorsvw.exe problem :)
http://techdows.com/2010/08/what-is-mscorsvw-exe-how-to-disable-it.html